# Error with createMuiTheme when using current and latest versions of material-ui

Tags: material-ui

I have forked the material-ui v1-beta branch, built it, changed the name in package.json to material-ui-beta to prevent it installing as material-ui which overwrites the current version.

This works fine until I want to define a theme using createMuiTheme from the beta version of material ui. This throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'secondary' of undefined
createTypography
node_modules/material-ui-beta/styles/typography.js:52
  49 |   fontFamily: fontFamily,
  50 |   letterSpacing: '-.04em',
  51 |   lineHeight: 1,
> 52 |   color: palette.text.secondary
  53 | },
  54 | display3: {
  55 |   fontSize: 56,
```

I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue or can point out where I'm going wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this problem today and it had to do with the value being passed for `palette.text` in `createMuiTheme`. we had previously been passing

```
const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: colors[customer.colors.primary],
    secondary: colors[customer.colors.secondary],
    text: colors.white,
    type: 'light',
    background: colors.white,
    grey: colors.grey
  },
});
```

it turns out that the value `colors.white` does not have a `secondary` attribute (not listed on the [colors page](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/style/color/)). because we don't have customizations for `text`, `background`, and `grey`, we decided to remove them from the options object. however, it looks like you can choose any of the other colors listed in the docs for the `text` value